# How Jax-RS used in Restfull Webservices and JAX-WS used in SOAP ?

Tags: rest, jax-rs, jax-ws

Jax-ws( Java API for XML webservice) 
      ---- is a set of API for creating a webservices in xml format . 
 jax-rs (java API used for developer to develop the rest web application easily)

I am trying to understand where exactly this api is used .

Please help me in understand the concept .

Answer (score 1):

SOAP and Restfull Webservices are just standards. They describes how a SOAP/Rest web services should be. For example a SOAP web service call starts with an Envelope and can have a (Soap) Header and (Saop) Body. Also SOAP services calls uses POST http method as default. For more detail, please check [SOAP specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-soap12-part0-20070427/) and [RESTful web services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

So, java communutiy also tries to follows these specifications. But instead just copying these specifications to java environment, they build their api's on the top of these.

Let me try to explain this with an example, lets say you are developing a "Hello, World" service. You want to use SOAP as your service architecture. When you finish designing your service, you probably write your own WSDL document (which is in SOAP specification). In WSDL document you define your object using XML, and also define your service methods with a SOAPAction and operation tag. Like this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://helloworld.bahadirakin.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="HelloWorldServiceService" targetNamespace="http://helloworld.bahadirakin.com/">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://helloworld.bahadirakin.com/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://helloworld.bahadirakin.com/">
  <xs:complexType name="helloRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="helloRequest" nillable="true" type="helloRequest"/>
  <xs:element name="sayHelloResponse" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="sayHelloResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:sayHelloResponse" name="sayHelloResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="sayHello">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:helloRequest" name="helloRequest">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="HelloWorldService">
    <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:sayHello" name="sayHello">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:sayHelloResponse" name="sayHelloResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="HelloWorldServiceServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:HelloWorldService">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
      <soap:operation soapAction="sayHello" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="sayHello">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="sayHelloResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="HelloWorldServiceService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:HelloWorldServiceServiceSoapBinding" name="HelloWorldServicePort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/camel-soap/HelloWorldInternal"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

In this example we define a service which contains a method named `sayHello` which gets a parameter of type `helloRequest` and returns of type `sayHelloResponse`. And lets look what we defined as `sayHelloResponse`

```
<xs:element name="sayHelloResponse" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
```

It is just a string, defined using XML.

But when you change your perspective from XML to JAVA, you won't define your object as XML instead you will use your Classes. Also, you won't define your methods using SOAPAction's or any other xml tag. You just write your methods in JAVA. You will need a framework to make these kind of changes for you. Otherwise you will end up writing your framework to make these kind of change possible. And also, now your are able to define a simple POJO as a SOAP (or Rest) services with just some annotations.

So, JAX-WS and JAX-RS are just names of java standards (apis) for handling SOAP and Restful Service architectures. By using these frameworks you will never worry about how to change a Java method to a web services method. Here is JAX-WS version of the WSDL given above. First lets look at our request parameter `helloRequest`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "helloRequest", propOrder = {
    "firstName",
    "lastName"
})
public class HelloRequest {

    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    // GETTERS & SETTERS
}
```

As you can see it is simply a POJO. And now lets look our service interface.

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://helloworld.bahadirakin.com/", name = "HelloWorldService")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface HelloWorldService {

    @WebResult(name = "sayHelloResponse", targetNamespace = "http://helloworld.bahadirakin.com/", partName = "sayHelloResponse")
    @WebMethod
    public java.lang.String sayHello(
        @WebParam(partName = "helloRequest", name = "helloRequest", targetNamespace = "http://helloworld.bahadirakin.com/")
        HelloRequest helloRequest
    );
}
```

As you can see there is no Envelope, no Body, no HTTP POST or anything else. You just write a java interface and match them with SOAP using JAX-WS API. Yes, you still need to have a basic understanding of what is SOAP. But you can easily develop a SOAP web service thanks to JAX-WS api.

Since JAX-WS and JAX-RS are just APIs, there are different implementation of each api. For example for JAX-WS there are [metro](https://jax-ws.java.net), [cxf](http://cxf.apache.org), [Axis2](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/jaxws-guide.html) implementations. And for JAX-RS there are [jersey](https://jersey.java.net), [cxf](http://cxf.apache.org) etc. implementations. They fallows same API but implementations are totally different. Also Applications Servers provide their own implementations.

But they still need to convert java object to XML since SOAP specification forces it. There are some other libraries that convert Java to Xml and XML to java. Such as [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net) and [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io). Also, when you develop rest services you probably want to convert your java objects to JSON. There are some tools for that purpose too like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [GSon](https://github.com/google/gson).

But JAX-RS and JAX-WS are not the only way to develop REST or SOAP web services. For example in order to develop RESTful web services you may use [SpringMVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

"Then, Why should I use a specification" you may ask. It is totally up to you to use a specification or not. Theoretically, If you use a specification, you can change your implementation any time you want. But, since each different implementations provides different cool features, you probably end up a highly coupled application. So you may not change that easily.